# Почему NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, scanner, поток-ввода

Имеется класс действие, с помощью которого пользователю выводится запрос на ввод имени:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EnterName {
    private String name;
    Scanner s;

    public String EnterName(){
    s = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true){
        this.name = s.nextLine();
        if(this.name.trim().length() == 0)
            System.out.print("[ОШИБКА]:\n\t-Должен быть введен хотя бы один символ.\nПовторите ввод: ");
        else {
            s.close();
            return this.name;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

В данном классе создается поток ввода `Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)` с именем `s` и в конце, если введен хотя бы один символ, то данный поток закрывается. И так каждый раз при вызове метода `EnterName()` происходит создание потока и его закрытие. Смотрим далее.

Далее имеется класс `Bank` и `Client`, которые наследуются от класса `EnterName`, чтобы использовать его метод `EnterName()` с целью избежания дублирования куска кода:

```
package com.company;

// БАНК

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Bank extends EnterName{
    private String name = "";   // название Банка

    ArrayList<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addClient(){
    clients.add(new Client());
    }

    Bank(){
    System.out.print("Введите название Банка: ");
    this.name = EnterName();
    }
}


package com.company;

// КЛИЕНТ

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Client extends EnterName {
    private String name = "";   // имя клиента

    ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

    Client(){
    System.out.print("\nВведите имя клиента: ");
    this.name = EnterName();
    }
}
```

Далее в классе `Main` происходит создание объекта класса `Bank` и на консоли появляется предложение ввода названия банка. Вводим название - всё, ок. Далее выводится на консоли предложение ввода имени клиента и тут сразу вылазит исключение. Почему?

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bank b = new Bank();

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        b.addClient();

    }
}
```

Но если в методе `EnterName()` закомментировать закрытие потока `s.close()` - то всё ок. Почему так?

**Мои рассуждения:**

После ввода названия банка, происходит считывание до первого пробела, пользователь нажимает клавишу `Enter`, которая ещё делает такое действие, как добавление в поток ввода символа `\n` - символ перехода на новую строку, который и заносится уже в `s.nextLine()` при следующем вводе. Но тут вопрос - поток то создается заново? Где хранится тогда тот самый символ `\n`?

Comment: `System.in` - это `"The "standard" input stream."`. Для чтения с консоли он должен быть открыт. `s.close()` просто-напросто закрывает поток `System.in`. Далее вы создаете снова `Scanner` с параметром в виде потока `System.in`. А он закрыт. Вы же не можете считать что-либо с закрытого потока, правильно? Это и есть причина ошибки.

Comment: @Miron, Как правильно тогда реализовать закрытие потока? И нужно ли вообще его закрывать после каждого успешного ввода имени путем вызова метода `s.nextLine()`?

Comment: Не нужно, конечно