# Почему приповторной итерации метод hasNextLine возвращает ложь?

Tags: java, scanner

Если кратко, то у меня в `main` методе есть бесконечный цикл. На первой итерации цикла все идёт нормально, но начиная со второй Scanner начинает вести себя не ожиданно.
Дальше фрагмент цикла.

```java
    while (true) {
        int variable1 = 0;
        int variable2 = 0;

        String str = "";
        do {
            try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
                if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
                    str = scan.nextLine();
                }
            }
        } while (str.length() != 4);
```

А именно метод `hasNextLine()` возвращает ложь, из-за чего на второй итерации он не позволяет ввести данные с клавиатуры, а использует значение по-умолчанию, т.е. `str = "";`
2 вопроса: 1. Почему это происходит? 2. Как это исправить не прибегая к next() (*так просто, на будущее*).
Я так же нашёл похожий вопрос про ввод 2 чисел и операции и то, что nextLine() читает до первого `\n` из-за чего и происходит ввод пустой строки, только моя проблема *вроде* немного отличается

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: 1) [После Scanner.close() как работать со scanner?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721901/); 2) [Почему NoSuchElementException: No line found](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084957/); 3) [Не записывает данные в файл. Выбрасывает исключение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1486078/) и т.д. -- данная "проблема" всплывает почти каждую неделю

Comment: Вы правы, и впрямь дубликат. А раз всплывает так часто значит нет или мало популярных книжек про InputStream

Comment: Да, есть подводные камни, например, в документации класса `InputStream` указано, что метод `close` ничего не делает: [_The close method of `InputStream` does nothing._](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#close()), упуская из виду, что это абстрактный класс и на самом деле вызывается метод из какой-либо реализации, типа `BufferedInputStream` [_Once the stream has been closed, further read(), available(), reset(), or skip() invocations will throw an IOException_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#close())

Comment: И в учебниках _часто_ акцентируется, что правило хорошего тона - _всегда_ закрывать ресурсы, но нюанс в том, что `System.in` создаётся и открывается не программистом, а системой/виртуальной машиной: [_`System.in - The "standard" input stream. This stream is already open and ready to supply input data._](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in), то есть вне зоны ответственности прикладного кода.  А так проблему можно обнаружить и раньше, например, [2013 год: Закрытие потока ввода/вывода](https://www.cyberforum.ru/java/thread982803.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, почему в вашем понимании сканер ведет себе неожиданно?
Вы используете конструкцию try-with-resourses. В эту конструкцию передается сканер, в аргументах которого System.in, а System.in - системная переменная, возвращающая InputStream. Другими словами вы получаете InputStream из системной переменной, т.е. фактически вы его не открывали и программных средств для его открытия у вас нет. После первой итерации данный InputStream  закрывается средствами конструкции try-with-resourses. Посему на второй итерации вы сделать не можете ровным счетом ничего: открыть самостоятельно данный поток вы не можете, а единственный поток ввода, открытый для вас системой, хранившийся в переменной System.in, вы закрыли на предыдущем шаге. Шах и мат. Мораль: нечего закрывать ресурсы, которые вы не открывали. Решение проблемы выглядит так:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    int variable1 = 0;
    int variable2 = 0;
    String str = "";
    do {
        if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.print("Enter Value: ");
            str = scan.nextLine();
        }
    } while (str.length() != 4);
}
```

Comment: Серьёзно?! Я и не думал что его можно просто закрыть, так сказать "раз и навсегда". Ладно буду знать, спасибо

Comment: @HardTaker а почему нельзя? это InputStream, наследующийся от Closeable, у которого, соответтсвенно, существует единственный метод void close(). посему, если вызвать этот метод, то InputStream закроется. проблема же не в закрытии, а в том, что его открывает система, а не вы. а имея под руками лишь переменную System.in вы никак не можете управлять открытием данного InputStream